# How to get a list of all folders that have write permission for IUSR account?

Tags: iis, iis-8, iusr

I need to find a way to get a list of all folders and files inside of a master folder that have write permissions set for the IUSR account in IIS8 on Windows Server 2012.

I did a google search and could not find any scripts or tools that would allow me to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to add to the fun: you may need to enumerate virtual directories beneath the "master folder" as well, as they're considered part of that namespace.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the tool http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897332.aspx access enum (part of MS sysinternals suite) to enumerate all changes to permissions.

by default it only shows the locations where permissions change to be less restrictive than the parents - you can change this to show all permission changes. you can save the results out and clean them up.

you could take a look at this powershell script - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/db715d17-f4bf-4e4a-b467-c8d2ffddad02/getacl-for-a-particular-user?forum=winserverpowershell and modify it for your purposes